# How can I add CDN in React.js

Tags: reactjs

how to add CDN in react project, index.html file for text styling ?

tried to  add a  CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css under  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" /> but text style is same like it was before

Comment: Show how you are adding the CDN.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.